# Are there any animals whose genome haven't been sequenced yet?

Tags: genetics, dna-sequencing

I referred to a few websites and it seems like almost every animal's genome has been sequenced. However, are there any animals that haven't yet been sequenced? If so, can you provide the list here or provide the link to the website which provides that information??

Comment: There are 60,000 species of beetles, you really think people have sequenced them all?

Comment: @swbarnes2 We're on our way to doing so...

Answer (score 4):

Wikipedia maintains an (incomplete) list of sequenced animal genomes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sequenced_animal_genomes).

There are a [few million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_biodiversity) living species of animals, we're not that close to sequencing them all, and listing them all doesn't make much sense.

I'd recommend starting from the animals that have been sequenced, and in particular, animals from particular families or smaller taxa, if you'd like more detailed information.

Comment: I see there are a lot of animals that we haven't yet sequenced but I mean are there like any animals that are beneficial to humans in some way, hence it's worth sequencing, but it hasn't yet been done? I thought about choosing chimpanzee but it has already been sequenced.

Comment: @ZetaFox "Beneficial to humans in some way" is a pretty broad criterion that could likely include every animal there is with some justification.

Comment: @ZetaFox A lot of focus is actually on those that are harmful to humans, which is why you'll find thousands upon thousands of sequenced strains for many pathogens.

Comment: @jakebeal I kind of read OPs comment as "beneficial to sequence" but that's a good point to emphasize in case I was reading too much into it.